# How to use MAX in CTE using SQL

Tags: sql, max, common-table-expression

I'm attempting to use a CTE and a MAX function to find the highest number in a grouping of countries.  Ultimately in this table trying to find the total number of vaccinations for each country listed by summing the "new vaccines" .  Here's my code so far:

```
WITH VacGDP (Location, gdp_per_capita, Total_Shots) AS
(
    SELECT 
        Location, CovidVaccinations.gdp_per_capita, 
        SUM(CAST(New_vaccinations AS bigint)) AS Total_Shots
    FROM 
        CovidVaccinations
    WHERE 
        Continent IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Location, gdp_per_capita, New_vaccinations
)
SELECT 
    Location, MAX(Total_Shots) AS Total_Shots
FROM 
    VacGDP
GROUP BY 
    Location, Total_Shots
ORDER BY 
    Location, Total_Shots DESC
```

This returns the following table:

| Location | Total_Shots |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 6868 |
| Afghanistan | 4015 |
| Afghanistan | 2859 |
| Afghanistan | NULL |

I'm ultimately trying to just have one row showing Afghanistan 6868, so one row per country in this database.

I'm sure this is something super easy to fix but I'm a bit lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove New_Vaccinations from your CTE group by
- Remove total_shots from your group and order by.

Also you mention you want to see per day but there are no date filters/indicators in your code?

Comment: Perfect thank you!  So adding the group by was complicating it and pulling each row that changed the SUM.  Not sure why I asked about "per day" originally but I edited that out. 
 Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. If you add your values to the group by clause it will do simply that, group by every individual value .